# Указатель объявляется в каждом проходе цикла. Правильно ли это?

Tags: c++

```
while(!somevalue)
{
    static int i=0;
    int *ptr= new int(i);
    if(!function(ptr))
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: А что вам нужно, понятие правильности весьма размыто... ? Это компилируется, но если function может вернуть true, будет утечка памяти

Comment: Почему указатель объявляется заново после первого прохода . Я так понимаю это не совсем правильно ?

Comment: Зависит от того, что такое `function`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, каким образом function влияет на то что указатель объявляется несколько раз ?

Comment: *"указатель объявляется несколько раз"* Конкретно в том, что указатель создается заново на каждой итерации, нет ничего плохого. От содержимого `function` зависит, утекает ли память.

Comment: По-хорошему, `function(ptr)` должна вернуть `true`, если она берет на себя освобождение памяти (может, не непосредственно - скажем, передавая владение еще куда-то), и `false` в противном случае. Впрочем, выделение памяти для одного `int` через `new` представляется мне не совсем удачным (в общем случае) решением... Так ли это необходимо?

Comment: @Harry, это просто пример

Comment: Это конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос - "*После первого прохода цикла указатель ptr станет указывать на другое значение при этом он объявляется заново. Правильно ли это? Как написать правильнее?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на вопрос, связанный с переобъявлением.
В масштабе вашего кода все нормально. 
Не важно, инициализировать указатель перед циклом, или каждый раз его объявлять.
Компилятор заботится об этом за вас, у него есть своя автоматическая оптимизация
(хотя мб конкретно этот случай к ней не относится)

В итоге мы получаем абсолютно одинаковый asm код в вашем варианте и в альтернативном

```
void uhh(){
int i;
while (true){
    i = 2;
    std::cout << i;
}
}

asm:
uhh():
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
.L4:
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  mov esi, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  jmp .L4
```

```
void uh(){
while (true){
    int i = 2;
    std::cout << i;
}
}

asm:
uh():
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
.L2:
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  mov esi, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  jmp .L2
```

[Переводил код на плюсах в asm код с помощью этого сервиса](https://godbolt.org/)